# I'm getting an error in the loop on line 36 and 68, and I don't know why

Tags: alpha-beta-pruning, python-chess

I'm making a chess engine using alpha-beta pruning for a project, and here is my code. I'm getting an error on line 36 and 68,and I'm not sure how or why. Please help me. Thank you for your answers in advance.

```
import chess

def evaluate() :
    if board.is_checkmate() :
        if board.turn :
            return -9999
        else :
            return 9999
    if board.is_stalemate() :
        return 0
    if board.is_insufficient_material() :
        return 0

    wp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE))
    bp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK))
    wn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE))
    bn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK))
    wb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE))
    bb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK))
    wr = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE))
    br = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK))
    wq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE))
    bq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK))

    material = 100 * (wp - bp) + 320 * (wn - bn) + 330 * (wb - bb) + 500 * (wr - br) + 900 * (wq - bq)
    return material

def alphabeta(position, depth_, alpha = float('inf'), beta= -float('inf')):
    """Returns [eval, best move] for the position at the given depth"""
    if depth_ == 0 or position.is_game_over():
        return [position.evaluate(), None]
    else:
        if position.turn == chess.WHITE:
            best_move = None
            for _move in [position.legal_moves]:
                new_position = position.push(_move)
                score, move_ = alphabeta(new_position, depth_ - 1, alpha, beta)
                if score > alpha: # white maximizes their score
                    alpha = score
                    best_move = _move
                    if alpha >= beta: # alpha-beta cutoff
                        break
            return [alpha, best_move]
        else:
            best_move = None
            for move_ in position.legal_moves:
                new_position = position.push(move_)
                score, move_ = alphabeta(new_position, depth_ - 1, alpha, beta)
                if score < beta: # black minimizes their score
                    beta = score
                    best_move = move_
                    if alpha >= beta: # alpha-beta cutoff
                        break
            return [alpha, best_move]
fen_ = input('Enter fen: ')
board = chess.Board(fen_)
_depth = int(input('Enter depth: '))
engine = alphabeta(board,_depth)
print(board,engine[0],engine[1])
board.push(engine[0])
```

Also, there are errors on line 2181 and 3602

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the corrected code (I explain what was wrong just after it) :

```py
import chess

def evaluate(position) :
    if board.is_checkmate() :
        if board.turn :
            return -9999
        else :
            return 9999
    if board.is_stalemate() :
        return 0
    if board.is_insufficient_material() :
        return 0

    wp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE))
    bp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK))
    wn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE))
    bn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK))
    wb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE))
    bb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK))
    wr = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE))
    br = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK))
    wq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE))
    bq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK))

    material = 100 * (wp - bp) + 320 * (wn - bn) + 330 * (wb - bb) + 500 * (wr - br) + 900 * (wq - bq)
    return material if position.turn else -material

def alphabeta(position, depth_, alpha=-float('inf'), beta=float('inf')):
    """Returns [eval, best move] for the position at the given depth"""

    if depth_ == 0 or position.is_game_over():
        return [evaluate(position), None]

    best_move = None
    for _move in position.legal_moves:
        position.push(_move)
        score, move_ = alphabeta(position, depth_ - 1, -beta, -alpha)
        score = -score
        position.pop()
        if score > alpha: # player maximizes his score
            alpha = score
            best_move = _move
            if alpha >= beta: # alpha-beta cutoff
                break
    return [alpha, best_move]


fen_ = input('Enter fen: ')
board = chess.Board(fen_)
_depth = int(input('Enter depth: '))
engine = alphabeta(board,_depth)
print(board,engine[0],engine[1])
board.push(engine[1])
```

So, first of all, alpha-beta is never used in chess programming like this. Instead, we prefer [the negaMax version](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Alpha-Beta#Negamax_Framework) of it, and here is the pseudo-code :

```
int alphaBeta( int alpha, int beta, int depthleft ) {
   if( depthleft == 0 ) return quiesce( alpha, beta );
   for ( all moves)  {
      score = -alphaBeta( -beta, -alpha, depthleft - 1 );
      if( score >= beta )
         return beta;   //  fail hard beta-cutoff
      if( score > alpha )
         alpha = score; // alpha acts like max in MiniMax
   }
   return alpha;
}
```

Then, in this line of code (`new_position = position.push(_move)`), you were doing something strange. The move is made on the board, and you never undo the move. And you create a variable like if the `chess.Board.push` method will return a `chess.Board` type. This is false. Instead, tou should use something like this :

```
position.push(_move)
... some code ...
position.pop() # undo the move
```

And the last bug is here (`board.push(engine[0])`). This is not making a move on the board, but your alpha-beta evaluation. So the good index is the following : `board.push(engine[1])`.

This gives a functional code.

**BUT**, to make tour chess engine better, an evaluation as simple as your is not enough. Material score of the board is not a really good indicator of who is winning. So, I recommend you to implement [PSQT](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Piece-Square_Tables) and a [Quiescent Search](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Quiescence_Search).

Comment: Thank you so much! I will improve my code, thanks for the suggestion!